# JavaScript, split object in 2, and push in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3 },
  { A: 3, B: 4, C: 1 }
]
```

And another array which is called "headers"

```
const headers = [
  ['A', 'B'],
  ['C']
]
```

I have to create an array similar to the first one but, with those objects splited by what `headers` have in it's arrays.

This should be the goal:

```
const result = [
  [
    { A: 1, B: 2 },
    { C: 3 }
  ],
  [
    { A: 3, B: 4 },
    { C: 1 }
  ]
]
```

I tried by doing a "base" array with:

```
const baseArray = []
headers.forEach((header) => {
  const objFromHeader = {};
  header.forEach((head) => {
    objFromHeader[head] = 0;
  });
    baseArray.push(objFromHeader);
});
```

That will give me the `result` array but with 0 values for each key.

And then loop for the first array and put inside another array the base array with the correct values.

Then I wanted to fill each key according to the value that comes from `arrayOfObjects` but here is where I can't see how could I loop that array of objects and put the correct value. The only problem with that approach is that the `result` array will have some 0 values that come from the initiation array that I'm using, it would be better to me to only put the objects that actually have values and not 0 (I was thinking on another function to delete those keys with value = 0...)

How could I achieve it in a better way?

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/Lpscz6vt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over an object, use `findIndex` on the `headers` to identify which index in the headers array the property being iterated over should go into. Create an object there if it doesn't exist yet, and set the property.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  { A: 1, B: 2, C:3 },
  { A: 3, B: 4, C:1 }
];
const headers = [
  ['A', 'B'],
  ['C']
];

const toResultItem = (object) => {
  const resultItem = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    const headersIndex = headers.findIndex(arr => arr.includes(key));
    resultItem[headersIndex] ??= {};
    resultItem[headersIndex][key] = value;
  }
  return resultItem;
};
console.log(arrayOfObjects.map(toResultItem));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting some babel problem with this code due `resultItem[headersIndex] ??= {};` but I will find another way to do the same

Comment: `if (!resultItem[headersIndex]) resultItem[headersIndex] = {};`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3 },
  { A: 3, B: 4, C: 1 },
];
const headers = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']];
const result = arrayOfObjects.map((obj) =>
  headers.map((header) =>
    header.reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
      return Object.keys(acc).reduce((newAcc, key) => {
        if (acc[key]) {
          newAcc[key] = acc[key];
        }
        return newAcc;
      }
        , {});
    }, {})
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I picked the other one because it was first, it has some explanation and this one has some `undefined` when no key is found on the initial array, but it gave me an idea to use. Thanks.

Comment: Edited for undefined. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

**`Array.forEach` implementation**

**Logic**

- Loop through `arrayOfObjects` array.
- Inside that, loop through `headers` array.
- Inside that, loop through each array in the `headers` array.
- Create an empty object and assign the property from nodes in `headers` array with values from objects in `arrayOfObjects` array.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
    { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3 },
    { A: 3, B: 4, C: 1 }
];

const headers = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['C']
];

const baseArray = []
arrayOfObjects.forEach((obj) => {
    const childNode = [];
    headers.forEach((head) => {
        const node = {};
        head.forEach((key) => node[key] = obj[key]);
        childNode.push(node);
    });
    baseArray.push(childNode);
});
console.log(baseArray)
```

**`Array.map` and `Array.reduce` implementation.**

Using the same logic implementes in the above solution, we can rewrite this using `Array.map` and `Array.reduce` as below.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
    { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3 },
    { A: 3, B: 4, C: 1 }
];

const headers = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['C']
];

const output = arrayOfObjects.map((obj) => {
    return headers.map((header) => {
        return header.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc[curr] = obj[curr];
            return acc;
        }, {});
    })
})
console.log(output);
```